# pip install tensorflow-gpu not downloading

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

When I pip install tensroflow-gpu, the download reaching
67.7/455 MB gives me this error.

```
    C:\Users\Zouzou>pip3 install tensorflow-gpu
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-2.10.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (455.9 MB)
     ----- ---------------------------------- 67.7/455.9 MB 49.1 kB/s eta 2:11:48
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zouzou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 435, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "C:\Users\Zouzou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 516, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "C:\Users\Zouzou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 90, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)

  File "C:\Users\Zouzou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 463, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
```

I am using python 3.9.10 and I have a Nvidia GeForce 610M. Note, my computer becomes hot during the download.

Comment: Is this the full stacktrace ?

Comment: Most likely, this is a timeout issue because of a slower connection. Add a timeout setting like `--timeout 10000` to your pip command and try

Comment: no it's not complete, I added the complete one but stackoverflow told me "stackoverflow It looks like your post is mostly code" so I cut

Comment: ok, i will try the --timeout

Comment: indeed, that was the problem, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The download time was too long. Solution:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu --timeout 1000
```